# Remove page from Navigation stack - xamarin.forms

Tags: navigation, xamarin.forms

In my app structure is like below,
List Page -> Detail Page -> Edit Page

and in edit page there is button "Delete" which removes data from database.

Now my problem is to navigate user from Edit page to List Page,

I'm using Navigation.popasync 2 times for this, but on detail page i'm getting error from service that no such record exist.

How can i properly navigate user from Edit page to list page?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
// Remove page before Edit Page
this.Navigation.RemovePage (this.Navigation.NavigationStack [this.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
// This PopAsync will now go to List Page
this.Navigation.PopAsync ();
```

Comment: Because it helps explain what's going on perhaps? You know, the same reason we normally write comments!

Comment: this is a very bad suggestion. on uwp for example, you will get an error telling you that " you cant remove page, you are on", it occurs also on android but not always. if you are pushing async and if push event is slower than popevent, it occurs. on IOS i am not not sure.

Comment: I have implemented this on android/iOS and it worked perfectly. I didn't checked in UWP

Comment: @Hetal Credits should be to this. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57130/remove-page-from-navigation

Comment: ouch, System.ArgumentException: Page to remove must be contained on this Navigation Page, oh my what a restriction!

Comment: @NickKovalsky Is page is pushed modally?

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this:

```
var _navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation; 
var _lastPage = _navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault(); 
//Remove last page
_navigation.RemovePage(_lastPage);
//Go back 
_navigation.PopAsync();
```

---

But if you need to navigate to the root page you can use this:

```
var _navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;
_navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
```

Sends you back to your main page..

Comment: this might not necessarily remove the detailpage from the stack. if you check pages in navigationstack, you might see detailpage still in the memory.

Answer (score 3):

That will be because your detail page is trying to load a record that no longer exists on an OnAppearing or some other event. As such just put a condition at the top of if the record is null to not load the page.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help someone!

```
var PreviousPage = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2;

var PageYouWantCheck= typeof(NameOfPage);

if(Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack[PreviousPage].GetType() == PageYouWantCheck)
{
     var pageToRemove = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack[PreviousPage];
     Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(pageToRemove);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those who have `FlyoutPage` or `MasterDetailPage` as `MainPage`, note that `Navigation.RemovePage()` requires a `NavigationPage`. `FlyoutPage` does not inherit from `NavigationPage`, it inherits from `Page`.

We normally have our Flyout's `Detail` page as a `NavigationPage`. Hence, we must get NavigationPage from our Flyout's Detail page.

This can be done as:

```cs
var navigationPage = (Application.Current.MainPage as FlyoutPage).Detail as NavigationPage;
navigationPage.Navigation.RemovePage(navigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[navigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
```