# Move tabs to bottom with Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm trying to convert my Xamarin.Forms app from a MasterDetailPage with Menu and TabPage to the new Xamarin.Forms Shell.

I'm trying to move the tabs to the bottom. I also want them to look the same as the TabPage ones. Is this event possible with the basic Shell XAML layout?

[image]

**AppShell.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-MyApp.Views"
       xmlns:volDash="clr-MyApp.Views.VolDash"
       x:Class="MyApp.AppShell">
    <FlyoutItem Title="Dashboard 1" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Title="Signups" Icon="ic_assignment.png">
                <volDash:SignupsPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Events" Icon="ic_event.png">
                <volDash:AreasPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Mailbox" Icon="ic_mail_outline.png">
                <volDash:MailboxPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Rankings" Icon="fa_trophy.png">
                <volDash:MyRankingsPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Videos" Icon="ic_ondemand_video.png">
                <volDash:TrainingVideoCategoriesPage />
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Dashboard 2" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Title="Tab 1" Icon="ic_assignment.png">
                <volDash:SignupsPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Tab 2" Icon="ic_event.png">
                <volDash:AreasPage />
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent Title="Account" Icon="ic_account_box_white.png">
        <views:AccountPage />
    </ShellContent>
</Shell>
```

One alternative I found is to call a TabPage from the FlyoutItem. The tabs are shown properly at the bottom. However, I end up with an ugly gap at the top.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-MyApp.Views"
       xmlns:volDash="clr-MyApp.Views.VolDash"
       x:Class="MyApp.AppShell">
    <FlyoutItem Title="Volunteer Dashboard" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <ShellContent Title="Videos" Icon="ic_account_box_white.png">
            <views:VolunteerDashboardPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Organizer Dashboard" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <ShellContent Title="Videos" Icon="ic_account_box_white.png">
            <views:OrganizerDashboardPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent Title="Account" Icon="ic_account_box_white.png">
        <views:AccountPage />
    </ShellContent>
</Shell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not using `Tab` style to define the `FlyoutItem` . The Tab in Shell Apllication will be different with the tab of `Tabbed Page` .

The [`Tab` and `ShellContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/create#describe-the-visual-hierarchy-of-the-application) defined as follow in **Shell** Application .

- **Tab**, which represents grouped content, navigable by bottom tabs. Every `Tab` object is a child of a `FlyoutItem` object or a `TabBar` object.
- **ShellContent**, which represents the `ContentPage` objects in your application. Every `ShellContent` object is a child of a Tab object. When more than one `ShellContent` object is present in a `Tab`, the objects will be navigable by top tabs.

Therefore , here you can modify shared code as follow to have a try :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-MyApp.Views"
       xmlns:volDash="clr-MyApp.Views.VolDash"
       x:Class="MyApp.AppShell">
    <FlyoutItem Title="Dashboard 1" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">

            <ShellContent Title="Signups" Icon="ic_assignment.png">
                <volDash:SignupsPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Events" Icon="ic_event.png">
                <volDash:AreasPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Mailbox" Icon="ic_mail_outline.png">
                <volDash:MailboxPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Rankings" Icon="fa_trophy.png">
                <volDash:MyRankingsPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Videos" Icon="ic_ondemand_video.png">
                <volDash:TrainingVideoCategoriesPage />
            </ShellContent>
        
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Dashboard 2" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
      
            <ShellContent Title="Tab 1" Icon="ic_assignment.png">
                <volDash:SignupsPage />
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Tab 2" Icon="ic_event.png">
                <volDash:AreasPage />
            </ShellContent>
      
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent Title="Account" Icon="ic_account_box_white.png">
        <views:AccountPage />
    </ShellContent>
</Shell>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have different items in Flyout and bottom Tabbar using Shell?

Comment: @ThamaraiT Hi, do you mean different FlyoutItems? If so, sure.

Comment: consider Flyout has 'About Us', 'Contact Us' and 'SignIn / SignOut' Shell objects... Meanwhile bottom Tabbar has 'Home', 'Cart' and 'Profile' shell objects. Is it possible?

Comment: For detailed information about what I am asking, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085818/how-to-define-different-items-in-flyout-menu-and-bottom-tabbar-in-xamarin-forms/65086574?noredirect=1#comment115093325_65086574

Comment: @ThamaraiT Okey, I will check that.

Comment: @ThamaraiT Hi, I have checked that. It is impossible in Shell to achieve that your means. Because `FlyoutItem` and `Tabbar` will affect each of them, therefore you only can seelct one to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225391/discussion-between-thamarai-t-and-junior-jiang-msft).

Comment: @ Junior Jiang - MSFT as per out chat discussion I am using Menu Item objects in side menu. When I click on menu item(e.g. Contact Us) in side menu from Home page(bottom tabbar), respective page is added to stack. Now I click a page (e.g. Uniforms) in bottom tabbar, respective page is rendered without adding to stack. Because the page is in Shell visual hierarchy. Now I click Home page in bottom, Contact Us page is shown.

Comment: According to Hierarchical Navigation in official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/lifecycle#hierarchical-navigation, stack need to be cleared. But in my case, it is not.

Comment: @ThamaraiT Hi, the navigation stack need to be cleared manually in Shell. It can not be cleared automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084692/remove-page-from-navigation-stack-xamarin-forms

Comment: I checked that link. Is it possible to clear stack when we click each bottom TabBar objects?

Comment: @ThamaraiT It is possible. You need to use custom shell renderer for bottom tool bar. When clicking the tabbar item, you could use messagecenter to send message to forms to `PopToRoot`.